# Loading of plugin from dll

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dll, .net-assembly

I've started on a simple plugin loader that monitors a directory and loads plugins if the dll(s) in it contain the IPlugin interface.

```
public class PluginLoader : Dictionary<string, IPlugin>
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    private string pluginPath;

    public PluginLoader()
        : base()
    {            
        pluginPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "plugins");
        if (!Directory.Exists(pluginPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pluginPath);

        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pluginPath, "*.dll");
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }        

    private void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadPlugin(e.FullPath);
    }

    private void LoadPlugin(string path)
    {            
        IPlugin plugin = null;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type.GetInterfaces().Count(iType => iType == typeof(IPlugin)) == 1)
            {
                ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
                object instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                plugin = instance as IPlugin;
                // plugin is now not null
            }
        }
        if (plugin != null && !this.ContainsKey(plugin.PluginName))
        {
            this[plugin.PluginName] = plugin;
        }
    }        
}
```

This version of LoadPlugin() works, the plugin variable ends up being != null. This one, however, does not work:

```
    private void LoadPlugin(string path)
    {            
        IPlugin plugin = null;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName) != null)
            {
                ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
                object instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                plugin = instance as IPlugin;
                // plugin is still null
            }
        }
        if (plugin != null && !this.ContainsKey(plugin.PluginName))
        {
            this[plugin.PluginName] = plugin;
        }
    }
```

I just don't understand why. So my question is: Why does plugin end up being null in the second example?

Solution:
Problem was that I had two different `IPlugin` types because its assembly existed in two different locations. So deleting the `Framework.Lib.dll` in the plugin directory solved it.

Comment: After you succeed to load a plugin, use `break` to stop iterating over the remaining types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that the type implements an `IPlugin` with the same namespace but from a different assembly. The `typeof(IPlugin).FullName` would then match between your plugin loader and the plugin, but the implemented type still does not equal the expected type.

The first example does match the exact same type, in the second example you're matching by the `FullName` which only includes the namespace, not the assembly a type is loaded from.

To determine whether this is the case, try log the following value:

```
bool matches = typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type);
string expected = typeof(IPlugin).AssemblyQualifiedName;
string actual = type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

`typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type)` is probably what you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: expected equals actual, but matches is false.

The plugin loader is in the "Framework" assembly, the IPlugin interface is in the "Framework.Lib" assembly, and my test plugin ("Test" assembly) references "Framework.Lib" and implements IPlugin.

Comment: How about `string expected = typeof(IPlugin).Location;` and `string actual = type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName).Location;`? If `IsAssignableFrom()` returns false, then the first example should also result in null. Is the first matching type from example 1 the same type as the first match in example 2?

Comment: Yeah, the locations differ.. First location is `.\Framework.Lib.dll` and second location is `.\plugins\testplugin\Framework.Lib.dll`. You're right the first example should've returned false as well. Now it **does** return false. I don't know what I "broke" either.

Comment: Does it still run if you delete the `Framework.Lib.dll` from the plugin directory?

Comment: Sure does! And now the statements `type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName) != null`,
`type.GetInterfaces().Count(iType => iType == typeof(IPlugin)) == 1`,
`typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type)` are true. I think I get it now.. Thanks!